# Rats and snakes populations using calculus

Tags: calculus

On a certain island, at any given time, there are R hundred rats and S hundred snakes. Their populations are related by the equation:
$$(R−13)^2+16(S−20)^2=68$$
What is the maximum combined number of snakes and rats that could ever be on this island at the same time? (Round your answer to the nearest integer)

Can someone help me through this problem. we are using lagrange multipliers and I just cant figure out how to set this problem up. please help

Answer (score 2):

There is an interesting geometric solution to your question.

Notice that the graph of $(x-13)^2+16(y-20)^2=68$ is an ellipse

This ellipse can be written as a parametric equation: $\left(13+\sqrt{68}\cos t,20+\displaystyle\frac{\sqrt{17}}{2}\sin t\right)$

Note that $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{1}{4}\cot t$. We want to maximize $x+y$, meaning that we should search for the point on the ellipse where $\displaystyle\frac{dy}{dx}=-1$ (this is because $x+y=c$ has slope $-1$).

The value of $t$ at this point is $\cot^{-1}(4)$. Plugging this back into the parametric equation, we get the point $\left(21, \frac{41}{2}\right)$. Our final answer is $21+\frac{41}{2}=\frac{83}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

The maximization problem is $$\max_{R,S} R+S$$ subject to: $$(R−13)^2+16(S−20)^2=68.$$ The Lagrangian, $L$, is given by $$L(R,S,\lambda)=R+S+\lambda[(R−13)^2+16(S−20)^2-68].$$

---

In such problems start by identifying the objective function and the constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is
\begin{align*}
\max & \,\boldsymbol{1}^{\top}x\\
\text{such that} & \,(x_{1}-13)^{2}+16(x_{2}-20)^{2}-68=0.
\end{align*}
Let $$\mathcal{L}(x)=x_{1}+x_{2}-x_{3}\left((x_{1}-13)^{2}+16(x_{2}-20)^{2}-68\right).$$
The gradient is
$$
\nabla\mathcal{L}(x)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
1-2(x_{1}-13)x_{3}\\
1-32(x_{2}-20)x_{3}\\
-(x_{1}-13)^{2}-16(x_{2}-20)^{2}+68
\end{array}\right).
$$
Now, we consider $\nabla\mathcal{L}(x)=0$ for $x_{3}\neq0$. The
first two equations yield
$$
x_{1}=\frac{1}{2x_{3}}+13\text{ and }x_{2}=\frac{1}{32x_{3}}+20.
$$
Substituting into the last equation,
$$
\frac{1}{4x_{3}^{2}}+\frac{1}{64x_{3}^{2}}=68.
$$
Solving for $x_{3}$ yields $x_{3}=\pm1/16$. This implies the stationary
points are
$$
x_{1}=\pm8+13\text{ and }x_{2}=\pm\frac{1}{2}+20.
$$

> The solution is $(x_{1},x_{2})=(21,20.5)$.

Note that $20.5\times 100$ is an integer (the problem is specified in "hundreds" of animals), and hence this is a valid number of rats and snakes.

Comment: I got 13 and 20 already too. that means I got 33 total. and thats wrong.

Comment: @NoahDukehart: fixed

Comment: its not 37 either

Comment: It's either 37 or 41.5 depending on whether your book allows for a fractional number of snakes. See also Hrhm's answer below (they get 41.5 as well)

Comment: @par actually, it's 41.5 hundred snakes and rats

Comment: @Hrhm: oh, I see. My bad.

Comment: @par nah, I should have been more clear in my comment

Comment: I tired 37, and 41 and 42. Like none of them are working at all does it have to do with the fact that its measured in hundreds? so that it would be 4150?

Comment: @NoahDukehart: Yes, the problem was that I did not see the "hundreds" specification in the problem. $20.5\times 100=2050$ is an integer so we do not have to worry about fractional points in this case. You should read and understand both Hrhm and I's posts, and accept Hrhm's answer because he noticed this before I did.

Comment: it was 4150, thank you so much, you were both really helpful and really understanding

Comment: @NoahDukehart: consider upvoting the answers you appreciated and accepting (I recommend accepting Hrhm's answer)